# Телефонный номер. При вводе буквенного значения перевести в цифры. Python

Tags: python

Прошу помочь с решением задачи. Необходимо перевести буквенное обозначение номера в циферное. Input: 000 sinatra  Output: 000 7462872

```
def as_numeric(text):
    thelist=list(text)
    for letters in thelist:
         tel_numbers={
        '2':['a','b','c'],
        '3':['d','e','f'],
        '4':['g','h','i'],
        '5':['j','k','l'],
        '6':['m','n','o'],
        '7':['p','q','r','s'],
        '8':['t','u','v'],
        '9':['w','x','y','z']}

    if letters==tel_numbers:
        print(tel_numbers)
    else:
        break
```

as_numeric('000 sinatra')

Answer (score 5):

[translate](http://www.w3ii.com/ru/python3/string_translate.html) – возвращает копию строки, в которой все символы были переведены с помощью словаря

```
phone_dict = {ord(letter): str(num) for num, le in enumerate(
    ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz'], start=2) for letter in le}
print('000 sinatra'.translate(phone_dict))  # 000 7462872
```

Comment: Подходящее использование `str.translate()`. Можно ещё явно dict использовать: `''.join([letter2num.get(c, c) for c in text])`, где `letter2num = {c: num for num, letters in tel_numbers.items() for c in letters}`

Comment: Классное решение :)

Answer (score 0):

Исправил код автора:

```
def as_numeric(number):
    result = ''
    tel_numbers = {key : value for key, value in zip(range(2, 10), ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl',
                                                                    'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz'])}
    for i in str(number).lower():
        if i.isdigit() or i == ' ':
            result += i
            continue
        for key in tel_numbers.keys():
            if i in tel_numbers[key]:
                result += str(key)
    return result

print(as_numeric('000 sinatra')) # 000 7462872
```

Answer (score -1):

Из словаря `tel_numbers` сделал обратный – `phone_letter_by_num`, а после оставалось собрать новую строку:

```
def phone_as_numeric(text: str) -> str:
    phone_letter_by_num = {
        'l': '5', 'b': '2', 'n': '6', 'q': '7',
        'i': '4', 'j': '5', 'd': '3', 'x': '9',
        'h': '4', 's': '7', 'v': '8', 'w': '9',
        'g': '4', 'p': '7', 'k': '5', 'y': '9',
        'u': '8', 'a': '2', 'm': '6', 'o': '6',
        'e': '3', 'f': '3', 'c': '2', 'r': '7',
        't': '8', 'z': '9',
    }
    return ''.join(phone_letter_by_num.get(c, c) for c in text)


print(phone_as_numeric('000 sinatra'))  # 000 7462872
```

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать за что минус. Ответ неправильный или что-то другое? :)

Comment: Благодарю! Работает. Только  небольшое добавление. А если слово введено заглавными буквами?

Comment: @FrankSinatra, заменяете тогда `for c in text:` на `for c in text.lower():`, тогда регистр букв будет неважным

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @FrankSinatra, тогда примите ответ как правильный (галочка слева от ответа) и поставьте что ответ полезен (стрелочка вверх) ;)